# How to change local variable value by using method?

Tags: ruby, variables, binding

I wrote some code:

```
a = 4
b = 7
def swaps(g, f)
  g ^= f; f ^= g; g ^= f
end

swaps(a, b)
p a, b
```

I thought I wanted result: a value is 7, b value is 4, but I got result:

```
4, 7
```

Comment: And Andrey's answer demonstrates, you can do it. But the question is, _should_ you do it? For anybody using that method, it's going to be very surprising behavior. If you want a method to have side-effects, you should put it in a class and use instance variables. If you don't want to to do that, you should just have the method return the new values so the user can do `a, b = swaps(a, b)`.

Comment: Furthermore using a method might be a bit overkill when you can do `a, b = b, a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to those local variables inside your method.

You can play with it by passing `binding` but this shouldn't be used in real life:

> Objects of class `Binding` encapsulate the execution context at some
>   particular place in the code and retain this context for future use.

```
def change(local_variable_name, binding, new_value)
  binding.local_variable_set(local_variable_name, v)
end
```

Test:

```
a = 1

a                      #=> 1
change(:a, binding, 2) #=> 2
a                      #=> 2
```

Your case:

```
def swap(first, second, binding)
  old_first  = binding.local_variable_get(first)
  old_second = binding.local_variable_get(second)

  binding.local_variable_set(first, old_second)
  binding.local_variable_set(second, old_first)
end

a = 1
b = 2
swap(:a, :b, binding)
a #=> 2
b #=> 1
```

Reference:

- [`Binding#local_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set)
- [`Binding#local_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get)

Comment: Wow. It is amazing.

Comment: @J.Cube yea, Ruby is cool. Make sure to check all answers and select the one that solves your issue and mark it as accepted if provides what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Better I read comments before!
Credits to Jordan Running and Johan Wentholt**

I leave this post just to point out these solutions.

---

Maybe parallel assignment can do it, instead of defining a method:

```
a = 4
b = 7

a, b = b, a

p a #=> 7
p b #=> 4
```

Or, if it sounds clearer:

```
def swap(a, b)
  return b, a
end

a, b = swap(a, b)
```